# NGINX - Godaddy - ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am tying to use GoDaddy ssl with Nginx. I am having and issue getting this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

I did the following:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout img.example.com.key -out img.example.com.csr
```

Gave this to GoDaddy and requested a new cert.

Next I combined the two crt files into one.

Assuming your certificate file is called example.com.crt, use this command to create a combined file called example.com.chained.crt (replace the highlighted part with your own domain):

```
cat example.com.crt intermediate.crt > example.com.chained.crt

server_name example.com;
ssl_certificate /home/sammy/example.com.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /home/sammy/example.com.key;
```

I am now seeing this error when I try to start Nginx:

> sudo nginx -t
>
> nginx: [emerg]
>   SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl-certs/img.example.com.key")
>   failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start
>   line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY error:140B0009:SSL
>   routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)

Anyone know why I am getting this error?

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 35):

Had the same issue. Changing the encoding from `UTF-8` to `ANSI` did work for me.

Comment: md5 sums were ok in my crt and key files. I had no idea what else can be wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: I used `iconv -c -f UTF8 -t ASCII  myprivate.key >> myprivate.key`

Comment: I wonder why these crucial details never find their proper place in the instructions.

Comment: Converting the file using @TobyBeresford 's command above worked for me.

Comment: save as ascii / ansi - no bom

Answer (score 5):

Notepad++ encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI did it for me. Change Encoding, saved, scp / winscp / copy to server. done.

The Unix version of this is to save time with copy processes:

```
iconv -c -f UTF8 -t ASCII  /etc/nginx/certs/genprivkey.key >> /etc/nginx/certs/genprivkey.key
```

[image]